# Azure DevOps Pipeline: Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.Bcl.AsyncInterfaces, Version=7.0.0.0'

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-devops, azure-pipelines, powershell-core

I'm working with an Azure DevOps Pipeline that's designed to execute a PowerShell script stored in a repository. This script utilizes the "[rhubarb-geek-nz.NpgsqlConnection](https://www.powershellgallery.com/packages/rhubarb-geek-nz.NpgsqlConnection/7.0.2)" module to interact with a Postgres SQL database.

While the script runs flawlessly on my local machine, I encounter an error when attempting to execute it from the Azure Pipeline.

```
trigger:
- none

stages:
- stage: Dev
  jobs:
  - job: "Setup"
    pool:
      vmImage: 'ubuntu-latest'#tried with 'windows-latest' and 'mac13' 
    steps:
    - task: PowerShell@2
      inputs:
        targetType: 'inline'
        script: 'Write-Host "PowerShell $(pwsh --version)"'

    - task: PowerShell@2
      inputs:
        targetType: 'filePath'
        filePath: './setup.ps1'
        arguments: '-Env "dev"'
```

[image]

**Error:**
[image]

**Update (Nov-20):** setup.ps1

```
function Install-AdditionalModules {
    Write-Output "Installing the required modules"
    
    # This module is required to communicate with Postgres
    Install-Module -Name rhubarb-geek-nz.NpgsqlConnection -Confirm:$False -Force -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
}

# Install Additional Modules
Install-AdditionalModules

function Close-DatabaseConnection {
    [CmdletBinding()]
    param(
        [Npgsql.NpgsqlConnection]$connection
    )
    
    try
    {
        $connection.Dispose()
    }
    catch {
       Write-Host "The connection to the Database could not be terminated: $($_.Exception.InnerException.Message)"
    }
}

function Open-DatabaseConnection {
    [CmdletBinding()]
    param(
        [PSCustomObject]$commonConfig
    )
    
    $connection = New-NpgsqlConnection -ConnectionString $commonConfig.connectionstring

    try
    {
        $connection.Open()
    }
    catch {
       Write-Host "The connection to the Database could not be established: $($_.Exception.InnerException.Message)"
    }

    return $connection
}

function Add-Record {
    [CmdletBinding()]
    param(
        [Npgsql.NpgsqlConnection]$connection,
        [string]$commandText
    )
    
    $command = $connection.CreateCommand()
    $command.CommandText = $commandText

    try
    {
        $command.ExecuteNonQuery() | Out-Null
    }
    catch {
        Write-Host "The record could not be added to the Database: $($_.Exception.InnerException.Message)"
     }
}

$connection = Open-DatabaseConnection -commonConfig $config.commonConfig
Add-Record -connection $connection -commandText "Insert into ..."
```

**Update#2:** I tried adding but it didn't resolve the issue

```
Add-Type -Path "Assemblies\Microsoft.Bcl.AsyncInterfaces.dll"
```

Comment: What OS.  Looks like it was tested on Linux.  See : https://github.com/rhubarb-geek-nz/NpgsqlConnection/blame/main/README.md

Comment: I was running it on the ubuntu-latest azure devops agent

Comment: The OP tested on Debian, not Ubuntu.  Is local and remote both ubuntu and same version?  Is hardware platform the same? It could be the hardware is a different micro and requires different compiler options for gcc.  One stupid question.  Did you install the gcc executable on the machine?

Comment: Did you test the code on server locally before trying to run remotely?

Comment: I did run the code on Mac13. However, I am still getting the same error even with Mac13 agent

Comment: GCC with Mac13 agent may not work with a M1 (Arm64 / aarch64).  See : https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/730778/how-to-build-gcc-13-on-m1-macbook-pro

Comment: Could you please share some "setup.ps1" script snippets that can reproduce this issue?

Comment: @MiaoTian-MSFT, please see the update.

Comment: Hi @OneDeveloper, thanks for the update. But the error message in the screenshot is for the line `Setup -TenantEvn.....` The code snippet you shared does not seem to contain this line.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I successfully developed a Python script to fulfill my requirements. Here’s the code snippet:

```
import psycopg2

def add_record(connection, command_text):
    try:
        with connection.cursor() as cur:
            cur.execute(command_text)
        connection.commit()
    except Exception as e:
        print(f'An error occurred while adding the record to the Tenant Database: {str(e)}')
```

While PowerShell offers cross-platform compatibility, it does have certain limitations. In this instance, Python proved to be more effective.